# Is there a way to convert Float value into a String in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

I know we can use `Float.toString()` or `String.valueOf()` methods to convert a float value to string but they are not working in this case.

```
float num = 3.44;
String temp = Float.toString(num);
```

It works if I have something like :

```
float num = 3.44f;
String temp = Float.toString(num);
```

But Iam writing a program in which I calculate value of a fraction and I store it as a String, like

```
float num = 1/2.0;
String temp = Float.toString(num);
```

Now, this statement is throwing an error so how do I convert such values generated during runtime into a String.

Comment: the reason of your problem is incompatible type. is it not possible to use Double instead?

Comment: Or, y'know, `1/2f`

Comment: need to edit the title. the problem is not with the conversion

Comment: *Now, this statement is throwing an error* ... isnt a very helpful problem description. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`3.44` is a `double` literal. You can't assign it to a float as it has less precision and is a narrower type. You can do this

```
float num = 1/2.0f;
```

or

```
double num = 1/2.0;
```

I suggest using `double` as it has literally half a *billion* times the precision.

Thank you `Eric Postpischil` for the correction.

> this statement is throwing an error

You have a compilation error about a loss of precision. If you read the actual error you can google it to find a solution.

Errors are only thrown when you run the program after it has been compiled successfully.